# ionic 5: cordova iOS build fails after adding jitsi-meet plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic5, jitsi-meet

I am using https://github.com/findmate/cordova-plugin-jitsi-meet with ionic 5 project. It works fine on Android devices but not able to build iOS APK. I don't have any idea how to fix this error since this is the first time I am trying to build iOS app. Anyone please help me to fix this.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDRG7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below plugin to build for both ios and android.
I tried this in one of my ionic cordova applications it worked well.
No issues while building also.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-jitsi-meet-sdk

npm i cordova-plugin-jitsi-meet-sdk